# Selecting a value from Options popup and Saving it to Chrome.storage for use as value in background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

...I have a list of the Google domains from a wiki source, which I will add as values into an HTML select tag as follows:

options.html / popup.html

```
<select required='true' size='1'>
<option value=".com">Default: USA</option>
<option value=".co.za">South Africa</option>
<option value=".de">Germany</option>
<option value=".fr">France</option>
<option value=".com.tw">Taiwan</option>
<option value=".com.br">Brazil</option>
</select>

<div id="status"></div>
<button id="save">Select Region</button>

<script src="options.js"></script>
```

The user clicks the Chrome extension icon and sees this list. They choose one and saved to  chrome.storage then the page automatically restores it on DOMContentLoaded.

Update: I have modified an example to do the basics of the storage and retrieval:

Option.js

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function saveRegion() {
  var userRegion = document.getElementById('regions').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    userRegion: userRegion,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
console.log()
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}

// Restores select box state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.

function restoreRegion() {
  // Use default value = '.com' 
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    userRegion: '.com',
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('regions').value = items.userRegion;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreRegion);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', saveRegion);
```

The background page must then use the stored value of 'myRegion' to construct the url as follows:

background.js

```
function readRegion() {
  // Use default value = '.com' 
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    userRegion: '.com',
  }, function(items) {
    var myRegion = items.userRegion;
    console.log(myRegion);
  // Console prints out my saved value e.g .com.tw
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', readRegion);

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      "title": "Web", // 
      "contexts":["selection"],
      "onclick": IncognitoSearch 
    });

function IncognitoSearch(ocd) {

  console.log(myRegion);
  // Console prints out undefined

  var contextSearch = 'http://www.google'+ myRegion +'/search?q=' + ocd.selectionText;
  chrome.windows.create({"url": contextSearch, "incognito": true});

  console.log(contextSearch);
  // Console prints out http://www.googleundefined/search?q=etcetera

}
```

Console prints out undefined for the second log of MyRegion.

How do I use the stored variable that I retrieved?

Comment: Documentation here, with examples: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @Xan I have read through and modified the example to get a working options page. I would like to know if the variable I want can be passed from options to background page, or what method can be used to improve my example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is asynchronous. As such, you should use callbacks (and chains of callbacks) to use the values. That, or the [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). Callback example:

```
function readRegion(callback) {
  // Use default value = '.com' 
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    userRegion: '.com',
  }, function(items) {
    // The value is usable here..
    callback(items.userRegion);
  });
  // But not here
}

function IncognitoSearch(ocd) {
  readRegion(function(myRegion) {
    var contextSearch = 'http://www.google'+ myRegion +'/search?q=' + ocd.selectionText;
    chrome.windows.create({"url": contextSearch, "incognito": true});
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarity, I will learn more about callbacks and promises to go asynchronous.

Comment: Fixed the broken link